Лоадер появлятеся, даже если все видео кэшировано
Почему тэг video показывает лоадер, даже если все видео загружено? Это как-то можно убрать?


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    const createVideo = () => {
        const element = document.createElement('video');
        element.id = 'test-video';
        element.preload = "auto";
        element.controls = true;
        element.playsInline = true;
        element.style.cssText = "width: 300px; height: 300px;";
        element.src = "https://youtu.be/Q38hY8uHKs0"; //<----вставьте ссылку на видео
        return element;
    }

    setInterval(() => {
        const video = createVideo();

        document.body.innerHTML = '';
        document.body.append(video);
    }, 2000);
</script>
</body>
</html>





Так ютуб не даст вам скачать видео

Видео не из ютуб, а с наших серверов. Поэтому и написал, что надо вставить видео, которое будет работать именно у вас.

Добавил gif бага. После пересоздания тега video появляется лоадер, хотя видно, что все видео уже кэшировано.

Ну как минимум вы провоцируете браузер заново прочитать и декодировать видео из кэша, этот процесс ведь тоже не мгновенный
